# Bills and coin denomination program

Tags: c++, integer, finance

I am currently in an intro C++ programming class. We have an assignment where we have to convert a dollar and cents amount, say $192.89, to bills and coins using the least amount of both. Below is the program I have written.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    double TotalAmount;
    int DollarsConversion;
    int Change;     
    int Dollars;     
    int Hundreds = 0;
    int Fifties = 0;
    int Twenties = 0;
    int Tens = 0;
    int Fives = 0;
    int Ones = 0;
    int CentsConversion;    
    int Cents;
    int Quarters = 0;
    int Dimes = 0;
    int Nickels = 0;
    int Pennies = 0;

    cout << "Please enter the amount to convert: $";
    cin >> TotalAmount;

    //Dollars Calculation.
    DollarsConversion = TotalAmount * 100;
    Hundreds = DollarsConversion / 10000;
    Change = DollarsConversion % 10000;
    Fifties = Change / 5000;
    Change %= 5000;
    Twenties = Change / 2000;
    Change %= 2000;
    Tens = Change / 1000;
    Change %= 1000;
    Fives = Change / 500;
    Change %= 500;
    Ones = Change / 100;
    Change %= 100;

    //Resets the Stack to calculate for the cents.
    Dollars = TotalAmount;   
    CentsConversion = TotalAmount * 1000;   
    Dollars *= 1000;    
    Cents = CentsConversion - Dollars;

    //Cents Calculation.
    Quarters = Cents / 250;
    Change = Cents % 250;
    Dimes = Change / 100;
    Change %= 100;
    Nickels = Change / 50;
    Change %= 50;
    Pennies = Change / 10;
    Change %= 10;

    cout << "\nNumber of Hundred Dollar Bills: " << Hundreds << endl;
    cout << "Number of Fifty Dollar Bills: " << Fifties << endl;
    cout << "Number of Twenty Dollar Bills: " << Twenties << endl;
    cout << "Number of Ten Dollar Bills: " << Tens << endl;
    cout << "Number of Five Dollar Bills: " << Fives << endl;
    cout << "Number of One Dollar Bills: " << Ones << endl;

    cout << "\nNumber of Quarters: " << Quarters << endl;
    cout << "Number of Dimes: " << Dimes << endl;
    cout << "Number of Nickels: " << Nickels << endl;
    cout << "Number of Pennies: " << Pennies << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: double's do not hold a value exactly. Convert your number to an integer (the number of cents). Then use that to do your calculations.

Comment: Don't forget to use the `%` operator. It will simplify your code considerably.

Comment: Sorry, The identifier Pennies was initialized to int, not float in my program. Finally got my code to work properly. It was truncating the integer numbers CentConversion and Dollar. I managed a work around to cut the divisor to 1000, instead of 10000. Then removed the division of the Cents formula and just had them subtract from each other. Then changed the quotients of each of the change identifiers to be 10x what they were. All seems to work pproperly now! Thanks for your help I have edited the code to reflect this so that if anyone else is having this issue can refer to my corrected coding.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  A fudge I have often seen involves the use of floor() or ceil()  - you can guess yourselves how.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of copy-and-paste code, where the only things that vary are the variable name, denomination, and textual description.  You can generalize the logic.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Denomination {
    const int cents;
    const char *description;
};

const Denomination DENOMINATIONS[] = {
    { 10000, "Hundred-Dollar Bills" },
    {  5000, "Fifty-Dollar Bills" },
    {  2000, "Twenty-Dollar Bills" },
    {  1000, "Ten-Dollar Bills" },
    {   500, "Five-Dollar Bills" },
    {   100, "One-Dollar Bills" },
    {    25, "Quarters" },
    {    10, "Dimes" },
    {     5, "Nickels" },
    {     1, "Pennies" }
};

int main() {
    double totalAmount;
    std::cout << "Please enter the amount to convert: $";
    std::cin >> totalAmount;
    std::cout << '\n';

    int cents = 100 * totalAmount;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(DENOMINATIONS) / sizeof(DENOMINATIONS[0]); ++i) {
        std::cout << "Number of " << DENOMINATIONS[i].description
                  << ": " << (cents / DENOMINATIONS[i].cents) << '\n';
        cents %= DENOMINATIONS[i].cents;
    }
}
```

Also note:

- A somewhat common convention is to use this `NamingConvention` for types, this `namingConvention` for variable names, and this `NAMING_CONVENTION` for constants.
- Your `DollarsConversion` variable is misnamed, in my opinion, as it actually stores the number of cents.

Comment: That is much simpler, however we haven't really learned anything about data structs, arrays, or loops yet. I took the class a long time ago but can't fully remember what we learned. I will keep this in mind for the future if I need to build another one!

Answer (score 1):

Good first program. :-)

Logical and easy to read.

---

Overall, I don't think you need to fix anything (I see from 200_success post that you have not done any data structures. His post shows you the best technique).

One improvement is that you could split some common code out into a function.

I see the following pattern repeated:

```
    X = Change / Y;
    Change %= Y;
```

So you could put that in a function and then simplify your code.

```
    int countDenominationAndRemove(int& change, int denomination) {
        int result = change / denomination;
        change = change % denomination;

        return result;
    }
```

Then your main body looks like this:

```
    Twenties = countDenominationAndRemove(Change, 2000);
    Tens     = countDenominationAndRemove(Change, 1000;
    Fives    = countDenominationAndRemove(Change, 500;
    Ones     = countDenominationAndRemove(Change, 100;
    quarters = countDenominationAndRemove(Change, 25);
    dimes    = countDenominationAndRemove(Change, 10);
    // etc
```

---

OK. The next bit is going to be very nit picky.
You may want to just read it for now but you don't need to follow all this quite yet.

Doing this is a bad idea.

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
```

Yes it makes the code shorter to read. But it is a bad habit. Bad habits become muscle memory, and you will do this when it is also not appropriate and cause errors. So best to avoid this and use the full version of each of them (they are not that much longer to use).

```
 std::cout << "This is how I use cout\n";
```

---

Don't declare all your variables at the top.

```
    double TotalAmount;
    int DollarsConversion;
    int Change;     
    int Dollars;     
    int Hundreds = 0;
    int Fifties = 0;
    int Twenties = 0;
    int Tens = 0;
    int Fives = 0;
    int Ones = 0;
    int CentsConversion;    
    int Cents;
    int Quarters = 0;
    int Dimes = 0;
    int Nickels = 0;
    int Pennies = 0;
```

Declare them at the point you use them.

```
    int Twenties = countDenominationAndRemove(Change, 2000);
    int Tens     = countDenominationAndRemove(Change, 1000;
    int Fives    = countDenominationAndRemove(Change, 500;
    int Ones     = countDenominationAndRemove(Change, 100;
    int quarters = countDenominationAndRemove(Change, 25);
    int dimes    = countDenominationAndRemove(Change, 10);
```

For integers this is not a big deal. But like all bad habits they can become ingrained. This does matter for when you start using classes (probably a few listens down the road) but if you get used to it now then it will not be a problem later.

It also makes the code easier to read putting the declaration at first use.

---

Now that we declare at the same point we assign (see last block). We also notice that the variables never change. So we could mark them as const that way if you accidently try to reassign them the compiler will let you know you messed up:

```
    int const Twenties = countDenominationAndRemove(Change, 2000);
    int const Tens     = countDenominationAndRemove(Change, 1000;
    int const Fives    = countDenominationAndRemove(Change, 500;
    int const Ones     = countDenominationAndRemove(Change, 100;
    int const quarters = countDenominationAndRemove(Change, 25);
    int const dimes    = countDenominationAndRemove(Change, 10);
```

---

When asking for user input. You should check it worked.

```
    cout << "Please enter the amount to convert: $";
    cin >> TotalAmount;
```

Did they enter a real amount or did they type in "Poop"?

```
    cout << "Please enter the amount to convert: $";

    // The following reads user input and checks you got a valid value
    // from the user.
    if (cin >> TotalAmount) {
        // We got a real value
    }
    else {
        // Invalid Value.
        std::cerr << "Your input was invalid. Program exiting\n";
    }
```

If you know about loops you could ask until they put in a good value.

---

At first you use `DollarsConversion` then for all the following checks you change to `Change`.

```
    DollarsConversion = TotalAmount * 100;
    Hundreds = DollarsConversion / 10000;
    Change = DollarsConversion % 10000;
    Fifties = Change / 5000;
    Change %= 5000;
```

I don't think you need both variables.

---

Not sure whe you are doing this.

```
    //Resets the Stack to calculate for the cents.
```

At this point the `Change` value contains the "Cents" only.

```
    Dollars = TotalAmount;   
    CentsConversion = TotalAmount * 1000;   
    Dollars *= 1000;    
    Cents = CentsConversion - Dollars;
```

---

Don't use `std::endl` unless you want to force a flush.

```
    cout << "\nNumber of Hundred Dollar Bills: " << Hundreds << endl;
```

And you practically never want to force a flush. So prefer to use `"\n"

```
    cout << "\nNumber of Hundred Dollar Bills: " << Hundreds << "\n";
```